# ¿Porque sale vació el JFRAME en JAVA?

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Intento hacer una interfaz básica donde
    pida introducir 2 puntos (x,y) para luego
    mostrar el punto graficado.
    En el menu todo bien,
    pero a la hora de darle
    al botón de graficar,
    sale vacio.

```
No me genera error de Sintaxis, por eso se
me dificulta ubicar donde podria estar fallando.
muestra el menu normal.
el boton Borrar hace su funcion.
pero a la hora de clickear en GRAFICAR
sale completamente vacio.




El resto al parecer esta todo bien.
```

Sale la ventana pero totalmente en blanco. Si bien es cierto que es algo bastante basico, una apliacion bastante sencilla se me esta haciendo confusa.

Se quiere generar una GUI que pida punto inicial(x,y) y punto final(x,y) para mostrar dibujarla en el panel.

estoy usando [jcreator](/questions/tagged/jcreator) para la creacion del codigo.

### imagenes de la corrida del programa.

[image: menu GUI]

[image: Vacio]

```
//import
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
 //clase
public class Qw extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {
    private JLabel lpi, lpf, lxi, lyi, lxf, lyf;
    private JButton bB,bG;
    private JTextField txi, tyi, txf, tyf;
    private     Graphics g;

    //inicio
    public Qw(){
        //principal
        super("LINEA");
        this.setSize(600,600);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Jlabel
        lpi=new JLabel("PUNTO INICIAL:");
        lpf=new JLabel("PUNTO FINAL:");
        lxi=new JLabel("Ingrese X:");
        lyi=new JLabel("Ingrese Y:");
        lxf=new JLabel("Ingrese X:");
        lyf=new JLabel("Ingrese Y:");

        //JTextField
        txi= new JTextField (3);    
        tyi= new JTextField (3); 
        txf= new JTextField (3);    
        tyf= new JTextField (3); 
        //JButton
        bB= new JButton ("BORRAR");
        bG= new JButton ("GRAFICAR");  

        bB.addActionListener(this);
        bG.addActionListener(this);

        //posicionamientos
        lpi.setBounds(10,0,200,100);
        lpf.setBounds(300,0,400,100);
        lxi.setBounds(10,30,200,100);
        lyi.setBounds(10,60,200,100);
        lxf.setBounds(300,20,307,100);
        lyf.setBounds(300,90,330,30);

        //JTextField

        txi.setBounds(70,65,40,30);
        tyi.setBounds(70,100,40,30);
        txf.setBounds(360,60,40,30);
        tyf.setBounds(360,90,40,30);
        //Jbutton
        bB.setBounds(120,130,150,40);
        bG.setBounds(120,180,150,40);

        JPanel pnlContenido=new JPanel();
        pnlContenido.setLayout(null);        

        //Agregando 
        pnlContenido.add(lpi);
        pnlContenido.add(lpf);
        pnlContenido.add(lxi);
        pnlContenido.add(lyi);
        pnlContenido.add(lxf);
        pnlContenido.add(lyf);
        pnlContenido.add(txi);
        pnlContenido.add(tyi);
        pnlContenido.add(txf);
        pnlContenido.add(tyf);
        pnlContenido.add(bB);
        pnlContenido.add(bG);

        this.setContentPane(pnlContenido);
        this.setVisible(true);   
    }

    //Acciones
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //borrar
        if(e.getSource().equals(bB))
        {
            txi.setText("");
            tyi.setText("");
            txf.setText("");
            tyf.setText("");
        }

        //graficar
        if(e.getSource().equals(bG))
        {
            JFrame q= new JFrame();
            q.setSize(500,500);
            q.setLayout(null);
            q.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            q.setVisible(true); 

            int xi = Integer.parseInt(txi.getText());
            int xf = Integer.parseInt(txf.getText());
            int yi = Integer.parseInt(tyi.getText());
            int yf = Integer.parseInt(tyf.getText());

            g.drawLine(0 , ((q.getHeight())/2), (q.getWidth()),((q.getHeight())/2));
            g.drawLine((q.getWidth()/2) , 0, ((q.getWidth())/2),q.getHeight());

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawLine(((q.getWidth()/2)+xf) , ((q.getHeight()/2)+yf),       ((q.getWidth()/2)+xi),((q.getHeight()/2)+yi));

        }
    }

    //main
    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        Qw mostrar = new Qw(); 
        mostrar.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

¿Me he saltado alguna condicion?

Comment: Tu código tal como lo pusiste no compila, por favor por siempre un [mcve]

Comment: lista la edicion. La publicacion esta un poco mas detallada. Gracias.

Comment: Perfecto, deja lo importo a mi coolbeans para checar que está pasando

Comment: Ya está mi respuesta, hazme saber si es algo similar a lo que buscabas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listo, espero darme a entender.

Graphics es una clase que representa la configuración nativa del sistema operativo, por ello solamente con declararla no vas a lograr nada. Lo que normalmente se hace es que se obtiene en tiempo de ejecución para evitar crearla, o en nuestro caso, solamente la referenciaremos en el método de pintado de tu `JFrame`.

Hay una sintaxis especial para ahorrarte crear una subclase que consiste en poner unas llaves después de la inicialización y allí redefinir los métodos que deseas cambiar.

Por ejemplo:

```
JFrame q = new JFrame() {
  // código aquí para personalizar la creación de tu JFrame
};
```

Por ejemplo en nuestro caso queremos redefinir el método de pintado y poner allí tus rutinas que ya tenías:

```
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
     g.drawLine(0, ((getHeight()) / 2), (getWidth()), ((getHeight()) / 2));
     g.drawLine((getWidth() / 2), 0, ((getWidth()) / 2), getHeight());
     g.setColor(Color.RED);
     g.drawLine(((getWidth() / 2) + xf), ((getHeight() / 2) + yf), ((getWidth() / 2) + xi), ((getHeight() / 2) + yi));
   }
```

como verás cambiamos `q.getHeight()` ya que estamos redefiniendo desde dentro de lo que irá a `q`, y `q` no se ha creado... así que podemos usar dos sintaxis para eso, ponerle `this.getHeight()` o si estamos seguros que no se puede confundir con otro método que igual se llame `getHeight` simplemente borramos `q` y listo.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
//import

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
//clase

public class Qw extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel lpi, lpf, lxi, lyi, lxf, lyf;
    private JButton bB, bG;
    private JTextField txi, tyi, txf, tyf;
//inicio

    public Qw() {
        //principal
        super("LINEA");
        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Jlabel
        lpi = new JLabel("PUNTO INICIAL:");
        lpf = new JLabel("PUNTO FINAL:");
        lxi = new JLabel("Ingrese X:");
        lyi = new JLabel("Ingrese Y:");
        lxf = new JLabel("Ingrese X:");
        lyf = new JLabel("Ingrese Y:");

        //JTextField
        txi = new JTextField(3);
        tyi = new JTextField(3);
        txf = new JTextField(3);
        tyf = new JTextField(3);
        //JButton
        bB = new JButton("BORRAR");
        bG = new JButton("GRAFICAR");

        bB.addActionListener(this);
        bG.addActionListener(this);

        //posicionamientos
        lpi.setBounds(10, 0, 200, 100);
        lpf.setBounds(300, 0, 400, 100);
        lxi.setBounds(10, 30, 200, 100);
        lyi.setBounds(10, 60, 200, 100);
        lxf.setBounds(300, 20, 307, 100);
        lyf.setBounds(300, 90, 330, 30);

        //JTextField
        txi.setBounds(70, 65, 40, 30);
        tyi.setBounds(70, 100, 40, 30);
        txf.setBounds(360, 60, 40, 30);
        tyf.setBounds(360, 90, 40, 30);
        //Jbutton
        bB.setBounds(120, 130, 150, 40);
        bG.setBounds(120, 180, 150, 40);

        JPanel pnlContenido = new JPanel();
        pnlContenido.setLayout(null);

        //Agregando 
        pnlContenido.add(lpi);
        pnlContenido.add(lpf);
        pnlContenido.add(lxi);
        pnlContenido.add(lyi);
        pnlContenido.add(lxf);
        pnlContenido.add(lyf);
        pnlContenido.add(txi);
        pnlContenido.add(tyi);
        pnlContenido.add(txf);
        pnlContenido.add(tyf);
        pnlContenido.add(bB);
        pnlContenido.add(bG);

        this.setContentPane(pnlContenido);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    //Acciones
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //borrar
        if (e.getSource().equals(bB)) {
            txi.setText("");
            tyi.setText("");
            txf.setText("");
            tyf.setText("");
        }

        //graficar
        if (e.getSource().equals(bG)) {

            int xi = Integer.parseInt(txi.getText());
            int xf = Integer.parseInt(txf.getText());
            int yi = Integer.parseInt(tyi.getText());
            int yf = Integer.parseInt(tyf.getText());

            JFrame q = new JFrame() {
                public void paint(Graphics g) {
                    g.drawLine(0, ((getHeight()) / 2), (getWidth()), ((getHeight()) / 2));
                    g.drawLine((getWidth() / 2), 0, ((getWidth()) / 2), getHeight());

                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g.drawLine(((getWidth() / 2) + xf), ((getHeight() / 2) + yf), ((getWidth() / 2) + xi), ((getHeight() / 2) + yi));
                }

            };
            q.setSize(500, 500);
            q.setLayout(null);
            q.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            q.setVisible(true);

        }

    }
    //main

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Qw mostrar = new Qw();
        mostrar.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

[image: Programa de graficación corriendo]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Ruslan. Entre las opciones que habia probado estaba lo de poner "q.." y lo habia sustituido por "this.." como sugeriste, pero al no saber sobre la redefinicion del metodo no habia cambios. muchisimas gracias.